# Nexus 1000v VEM fails on 2 out of 8 hosts

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, cisco-nexus

I have 8 ESXi hosts. I do a fresh install from the installable CD directly to 4u1.

We have another 2-node cluster with a working Nexus 1000v primary & secondary. Everything's up and running.

I installed 6 hosts and everything worked great, migrated them to the Nexus DVS, and VUM installed the modules.

I did the 7th host, and when I tried to migrate it to the DVS, it failed with the following error:

Cannot complete a Distributed Virtual Switch operation for one or more host memebers.
DVS Operation failed on host , error durring the configuration of the host: create dvswitch failed with the following error message: SysinfoException: Node (VSI_NODE_net_create) ; Status(bad0003)= Not found ; Message = Instance(0): Inpute(3) DvsPortset-0 256 cisco_nexus_1000v got (vim.fault.PlatformConfigFault) exception

Then, I tried to do host 8, and got the exact same problem. It worked about 15 minutes prior when I did host 6, nothing changed, then went to host 7 and it failed.

If I try to remediate either of these two hosts, either patches or extensions, it fails.

Anyone else have these problems?

Comment: I've found DVS configs to be particularly troublesome to be honest - great concept but I'm not a fan of the configuration procedure. Are you manually configuring all the hosts or are you using Host Profiles - I've found profiles significantly reduce the possibility of minor mistakes that lead to major headaches.

Comment: Me neither, in fact our VMWare DSE said it's buggy and will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Given Distributed Switching is a paid-for licenced service that hasn't been out for 12 months you inherently MUST have a valid support contract with VMWare for this lot and as N1000 setup/config is a far from common or simple job I would strongly advise you log this problem with VMWare support.

Please don't think I'm being unhelpful, I'm clearly more than happy to help out in just about every way I can with SF questions but when there are vendor experts that you've paid to answer this kind of problem I would always suggest you go there first. Hope you understand.